# Allow non-gold-badge-holders to suggest multiple duplicates and change suggested duplicates

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

I frequently encounter the following situations when dealing with new questions:

- It's not quite clear which of multiple possible duplicates applies more to OP's situation
- After suggesting one duplicate, I eventually find a better one
- The OP edits/clarifies the question and the old suggested duplicate no longer applies, or some other one now applies better
- In many cases, especially in the case of newbie question ([even fairly well-written ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56829001/doubling-amount-per-day-need-to-convert-number-of-pennies-to-dollars-cents?noredirect=1&lq=1)), a question has multiple concerns. While the current workflow advises closing those as too broad, this isn't honored in practice (as too labor-intensive/unconstructive/not helping anyone, perhaps). Suggesting multiple duplicates looks like a far more constructive and far less labor-intensive way to help the OP.

Gold badge holders can freely edit the list of duplicates AFAIK after they close the question. I'm hereby asking for the same feature but for the list of *suggested* duplicates, before the question is closed, *that are being suggested by me:*

- Suggest multiple duplicates
- Edit the list of my suggestions

  - (could be optional to minimize the effort needed; but since the UI for this is already implemented, the overhead of this item shouldn't be too much)
- The OP sees the union of all the suggestions and when accepting a duplicate, can select all that applies (the displayed advice for them should probably say: "select 1-2 items that apply the most")
- All the suggestions of a particular user still count as a single close vote/flag
- (Optional) When close voting, one can select multiple duplicates

  - To avoid increasing the number of actions a reviewer needs to take, the UI could probably say (and implement) something like "Ctrl+click to select multiple/additional items"). Reusing the UI of some of the above items is also a possibility.

Comment: When was the last time anyone suggested anything and it actually got put into the system? This is perfectly sensible but I'd imagine it will get ignored as usual

Comment: I like the idea. I regularly find a question that matches, say, two dupes. Yet, I can only suggest one. The only thing to do is to close vote with one and add a comment with "also see Y" and hope a gold badge owner comes along to use both.

Comment: @Liam maybe somebody could make a fuss on Twitter.

Comment: @VLAZ then be sure to not write anything in your comment that would make the system auto delete it. That's quite frustating when you are the hammer holder and loose all these useful comments pointing to other targets. So never put "duplicate" nor "dupe" and never edit the original flag's auto-message.

Comment: "*While the current workflow advises closing those as too broad, this isn't honored in practice*" If it's not being honored in practice, then those users are using their single-vote power to close a question that *should* require multiple votes. Multiple duplicates is not a way to close broad questions with one vote, and we shouldn't do things to make it seem as though this is what users are *supposed* to be doing.

Comment: @NicolBolas by "not honored", I meant other users don't VTC as "too broad" as they are supposed to.

Comment: Go get yourself a Gold badge in your chosen specialities and it becomes a non-problem.

Comment: While this seems reasonable, I can think of a few score other bugs and features to address first. This seems to be a low use/need request.  Meanwhile, you can link to other questions in the comments and even ping the dupe-hammerer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You act as if getting a gold badge is trivial. It requires a significant amount of effort. There's no reason this shouldn't be available to others.

Comment: There is a reason it should not be made available to others, @jhpratt — it takes a significant amount of effort to get a gold badge and those who have worked for it should be allowed the privileges that accumulate as a result of that effort and those who have not yet attained those privileges should wait until they have earned the privileges.

Comment: Marking a question as a duplicate of multiple hardly seems like a privilege, it seems like common sense. I shouldn't have to link to an additional duplicate in the comments — that's just stupid.

Comment: The lofty requirements to earn a gold badge drive volunteers to frantically grab at low-hanging fruit instead of sensibly voting to close (no rep for closing).  If a user has completed 1000 Close Reviews in the Close Review, let them add to the close list.  (Don't have time to post a complete answer)  ...maybe the review queues will come down a little.  My php badge took far too long because I am not a FGITW poster.  I could have helped this community better sooner.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler [It's much harder to get a gold badge now than it was 10 years ago.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1054823/questions-per-month-and-average-score) And ever more questions asked now are duplicates -- thus not counting towards the badge if you do the right thing.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: It took me 14 months to get my first gold tag badge; another 14 for the second; then 11 m, then 4 m, then a rush of 4 with about 1 m each (8 gold tag badges in 4 years on SO). The remaining 10 that I have were at intervals of 23, 6, 10, 4, 4, 6, 9, 2, 11, 4 months. Yes, it takes time to get gold tag badges — 18 in 10.8 years. They're not meant to be easy to earn. As was said, it takes time and effort. If I'm a party to a question that needs the duplicate list edited, you could ping me with a comment and I'd review the recommendation and if I agreed, I would update the dups list.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm currently more than 2,5 times over the requirement for [tag:python] gold badge on the number of answers and still about 70 low on tag score. This suggests that average answer score now is a bit lower than what the badge designers anticipated.

Comment: Yes, please!!!!

Answer (score 10):

After over a decade of energetic content generation, it is my opinion that the metric for "trustworthiness" should slowly become decoupled from rep points as the be-all-end-all unlocker of permissions.

A volunteer that posted some basic answer back in 2009 which has since gathered thousands of upvotes, is not necessarily more trustworthy than someone who has performed 1000 reviews in the Close Review Queue.

In fact, I will further argue that stages of moderation privileges should only be unlocked after moderation milestones have been achieved.

Regarding the OP's question, I am in favor of making the close link list editing permission more accessible to those who:

- earned trust via their moderation actions and
- who want to simultaneously help the askers and the site at the same time in a meaningful and permanent manner.

This question is an excellent opportunity to reconsider how we reward people who positively serve this community.

Comment: Unfortunately, performing reviews is not a sufficient criterion, as many reviews are wrong. We don't want to start giving moderation privileges to people just for blindly clicking through the review queues. Yes, audits exist, but they don't catch all the problems, not by long-shot. Reputation as earned by contribution of useful content is a less-than-perfect system, but it is still superior to counting up review activities.

Comment: @Cody Do you think there will be a high volume of users who are "clicking through" 1000 Reviews in the Close Queue? (that's not snarky) I can appreciate your stance regardless.  I could still be happy with a compromise ... perhaps lower the rep requirement if over 1000 Close Reviews are done.

Comment: @mickmackusa 1000 reviews is not so much. It's 25 days of 40 reviews. So I'm not Cody but I do think so.

Comment: So how long until _you_ would trust a volunteer's ability to review? @ivan  It is worthy of the highest level badge AND not good enough at the same time?  25 days at 40 reviews per day seems like dedication to the cause, but if not enough, I could comprimise higher.

Comment: @mickmackusa How do you objectively judge if a review is "right"? Until you come up with a good criterion for that, there's no point counting reviews.

Comment: Incorrect/bad posts are upvoted too.  Nothing is completely reliable.

Comment: Votes are feedback from other users, a collective independent opinion on the post's merit. Review decisions don't get that kind of feedback.

Comment: If someone is doing a shockingly poor job of reviewing 1000 questions, that's not going to go unnoticed.  The ability to post a correct answer is very different from judging whether a question is suitable for the site.  I am happy to compromise and determine worthiness by two factors -- reach a (lower) rep threshold AND show dedication to moderation queues. After 10 years it harder to earn rep because almost every post is a closable duplicate.This forces users to earn points be quickly answering questions before they are closed

Comment: -- this race condition pits users who seek privileges (and users who don't know/care about the importance of closing questions) against the users who are trying to fight entropy.  I would like to see the model adjusted so people don't need to act uncooperatively.

Answer (score -4):

SO is (in an ideal world) building a repository of Q&A. Our goal is to help the millions of people searching for answers, not simply the individual asking the question. Multiple duplicates does the opposite.

When a question requires a vast number of sub-questions to answer, it is too broad and should be closed as such. Leaving such questions as duplicates hurts the end goal of having a searchable repository of Q&A.

We are not an interactive text book, and neither can we be one. When we close as a duplicate, helping the person asking the question is only a fortunate byproduct. Encouraging users to focus on the byproduct is counterproductive, to say the least.

> While the current workflow advises closing those as too broad, this isn't honored in practice (as too labor-intensive/unconstructive/not helping anyone, perhaps).

If this is the core issue, then we should be fixing *this*. When you have a leaky roof, you don't start by installing a drain in every room.

Comment: True enough. But the situation being described here is effectively that the first one or two drains are basically already in place and it isn't really in the stars that the roof is going to be properly fixed. So do you stick with the one drain and let the other rooms get water damage or do you just install more drains to just complete the job?

Comment: @Gimby would you say the same if the other close votes could be done with a single voter? Example, if you want to stop a question from getting answers because is too broad, you could just select too broad instead of hunting down the specific duplicates.

Comment: This answers the request in terms of multiple questions (although there have been suggestions that closing questions which ask how to, say, group an array of objects *and* average values as too broad is "ridiculous"), but not in terms of edits to the question and/or finding more better duplicates.

Comment: Closing as a duplicate to a canonical post about the topic may help drawing attention to the canonical post. More people reading it, learning from it, proof-reading it. In addition, the more a post is used as dupe target, the higher it get rated in the "frequent" tab. Therefore it might be sensible to change the closed-as-duplicate list to point at canonical posts instead of random ones. I don't quite see why you'd need to hold a gold badge to do this. Maybe a bronze badge?

Comment: "*When a question requires a vast amount of sub-questions to answer*" what if it's just two different well-known things that OP's code has trouble with? Or if there is a *single* problem but there is more than one dupe that explains it?

Comment: A question with multiple duplicates may not be too broad at all. In the [assembly] tag we'll get a very specific question but there may be multiple problems with the specific question that can be answered in a number of other questions. We do this all the time in that tag. In the comments we'll usually explain the dupe targets and their relevance to the question.

Comment: I mean... you can cast a too broad vote and let it age away, or cast a dupe closure and have it take immediate effect, then edit in the second one. I'd prefer the vote that actually does something (when appropriate).

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Debugging questions with multiple problems tend to have very low future value.  The quickest way to help that one person is often to point them at multiple duplicates, but that's still not really adding a lot of value to SO for future searchers because other than understanding a specific error message, debugging problems are rarely search-friendly. Like this answer says, we aren't an interactive textbook.  But yes there are good use-cases for multiple duplicates, where the behaviour being asked about is a consequence of two other things.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Well editing a dupe target is a different matter, one that I don't have a strong opinion on. It certainly has benefits and potential problems.