# How to deal with the OP editing their question after a duplicate closure to ask a new one?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question, specific-edit

[Here is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59194501/8620333). I initially closed this question as a duplicate. Today, I found it was reopened and I was surprised. After checking the question, I saw that it was a completely new question that has nothing to do with the initial one. It's also answered and the answer accepted.

Is such behavior allowed? It bothers me a little because it makes my closure vote seem *bad*. It's also an easy trick to have any duplicate question reopened: You delete it, you edit it to create a new one, you undelete it, you cast your vote and wait for the queue to cast the remaining 2.

I also think the OP did that because they're no longer able to ask new questions so they found a trick to overcome the ban.

Should I flag such action? I would rollback the edit but since now there is an answer to the new question, I will make that answer irrelevant.

The important fact here is that the initial question wasn't bad or off-topic but was a duplicate. The OP probably got their answer from the duplicate then decided to ask a new one. Without the duplicate it would probably be a different story.

The question: [Can I change a question to another question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291949/8620333) isn't a duplicate because I am not the OP asking if I can change the question or not. The question was changed to invalidate a closure, get reopened and answered. I noticed the behavior since I was involved in the closure. I am neither the OP nor the person who answered.

Comment: I mean at the end ... the asker asked a good question, and got a good answer ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I Change a question to another question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291949/can-i-change-a-question-to-another-question)

Comment: @Turamarth that question gives an answer to the OP but what about me? what should I do? I *think* such behavior is not good but I am not the OP. I noticed the behavior. There is also the fact that a closure was involved.

Comment: @JonasWilms but it invalidates my *legit* action and can be a good way to invalidate many closure like mine.

Comment: Why? You judged the question *back then* and *back then* it wasn't a good question. Things have changed. Reopening is a normal part of the process.

Comment: Also we explicitly recommend banned users to edit their questions in shape ....

Comment: @JonasWilms it was a good question but a duplicate and since it was a duplicate, maybe the OP found his answer and decided to ask a new one by editing it. This is against how duplicate closure works. If anyone do this it will be a mess.

Comment: @JonasWilms Don't twist the facts. Editing a question into a shape doesn't mean to replace it completely, which itself is actually a way to circumvent the question ban, by asking the new question in an old post.

Comment: @Turamarth yes closer but I cannot rollback in this case because I will make the answer irrelevant. That one is the opposite issue where the answer become irrelevant due to the edit and the rollback is good for it.

Comment: @tom well [which facts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) the advice we give to banned users does not actively prohibit this behaviour.

Comment: Temani, I would argue that it is still a suitable dupe for the general behaviour, but in this case we're too late for that. The answer already exists and we shouldn't invalidate it. Maybe leave a comment for OP to tell them that this isn't allowed behaviour and when you see another such case, then roll the edit back.

Comment: *when you see another such case, then roll the edit back* --> it's difficult to see them. I close a lot of question each day and I have to wait until monday for the SEDE to update to find if a question is reopened ... I don't think there is a way to identify such behavior. No one will automatically check the revisions of each question.

Comment: @JonasWilms That linked post does not allow users to ask new questions in old posts (or I don't find the paragraph where it does); it talks about _fixing_ posts, which is clearly different and even *"If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask one new one 6 months"* makes it clear that this isn't supposed to happen. Other meta posts (for example both dupe suggestions), on the other hand, clearly tell that this behaviour is not allowed .

Comment: @TemaniAfif feeling that your effort to find duplicate is wasted is not acceptable - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391793/477420. I'm not exactly sure if it is helpful so :) Waiting for an upvoted answer to appear and then closing as duplicate may help with keeping questions from being chameleoned into another one or disappear as soon as it closed as duplicate... but that is not welcome either.

Comment: I’ve seen good and bad examples of this behavior. Questions being edited to be good. Questions being completely changed into something different. Both are good outcomes for the site in that we get good questions. However, I don’t know if the latter is good behavior because it’s one of the factors that contributed to me stopping contributing to SO. Rather than mechanical policy, I believe the more important point to address is the human factor. SO is trying its best to reverse the “not welcoming” image, but there’s the reverse side of making sure that contributors keep feeling good.

Comment: It troubles me that someone’s close vote can make them feel _bad_. If that becomes a more widespread feeling, then contributors/moderation will eventually trend downward.

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume there would be no answer yet. Then the way to go is clear: rollback, close, comment.

But now there is an answer. If we were to rollback, we would effectively invalidate the answer. This is a lose-lose situation. The only thing that can be done now is, well, *let it be...*

Otherwise we could

1. direct the OP to this thread to make them aware that their action was not accepted and that they may not do that again.
2. clarify the [Meta advice for question bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) to *explicitly* prohibit that behaviour. (That might turn into a self fullfilling prophecy though).

Comment: and what about the future? this may happen (or probably happened) different times with different users, should we *let it be ..* in all the cases? And more important: How to identify such behavior to be able to stop them or roll back the edit in time?

Comment: @temani Maybe the reopen queue should show the diff view by default? Then the post would not've been reopened (in case the reviewers were paying attention)

Comment: Regarding (2): since the answer there is locked, I'll create a flag and ask for an update of the answer. (just letting you all know, so we only cast one flag, not many :D)

Comment: @Tom yeah well ... the self fullfilling prophecy thing ... Not sure if hinting the people that this possibility exists does us a favor ...

Comment: It exists and prohibits it explicitly, so I would say it helps, especially since that question is the main dupe target for getting out of bans, so having that rule there is quire useful in my opinion.

Comment: @tom I'm not quite sure you get my point here. ... Maybe we should formulate it in a way that does not imply that editing questions into new ones is a way to circumvent the system quite effectively ...

Answer (score -6):

If you think there's nefarious activity going on -- certainly flag it, that's what custom mod flags are for!

---

As for rewriting a question per se. It's generally acceptable to edit a question -- *as long as that doesn't invalidate existing answers.* And in this case, there were none.

This won't and can't make you "look bad" -- because after an edit, it's normal that a question can stop being a duplicate, or become a duplicate of something else. [This happens with unclear questions all the time.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386721/allow-non-gold-badge-holders-to-suggest-multiple-duplicates-and-change-suggested)

---

(Edit from comments:) On a second look, such a behavior skews the OP's statistics in their favor: now they have just 1 open question instead of 1 open + 1 closed. Since this statistic is used in automated heuristics as well as in manual checks, by doing this, the OP effectively forges their profile! This certainly falls under getting an unfair advantage/gaming the system and is thus more than a reason for a flag!

Comment: *because after an edit, it's normal that a question can stop being a duplicate,* --> In this case the duplicate process will be a mess and I don't agree. I close your question as a duplicate then you find your answer in the duplicate and you change to ask a new one ... this is against duplicate closure, I won't accept this and if it's acceptable as a behavior I will simply stop closing quesitons.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't quite see what exactly you are losing here. A number of questions with your closure mark on them doesn't count towards anything (there are suggestions to reward for finding duplicates with reputation or badges but they are just suggestions now). For the purposes of the site, an extra duplicate doesn't mean much, either. And for an OP, they are at a disadvantage compared to asking a brand new question: they have to go for the trouble of getting it reopened before they can get any answers -- this doesn't provide any unfair advantages to them, either.

Comment: @TemaniAfif So I would flag it but for circumventing the ban rather than for editing.

Comment: *A number of questions with your closure mark on them doesn't count towards anything* -> I am not aimaing to win anything or to get any reward. I am discussing a potential bad behavior that will make the process of closing question a mess because it take it seriously. Now we have only one question and in the future we may have more. If you think such behavior is not a big deal then why I have to waste my time finding a duplicate and closing question?

Comment: *they have to go for the trouble of getting it reopened before they can get any answers* --> there is no trouble since now we need 3 votes to reopen so the OP vote + only 2 and it's easy to reopen question when the duplicate is irrelevant because the question is a new one. In my example the question got reopened in less than 12h

Comment: @TemaniAfif Now that you mention it, _"Now we have only one question"..._ 1 open question vs 1 open + 1 closed does skew statistics for the OP in their favor -- so this can be considered an unfair advantage!

Comment: I don't care about the OP stats or my stats, it's about the whole site. This happened *one* time. What if it happen again (with the same user or another one) would you accept this? should we allow this? For me it's a clear NO.

Comment: @TemaniAfif This _is_ about the site. Stats like this are used for various heuristics -- including question bans -- as well as manual checks by mods. So the OP is basically forging their profile. Clearly that's gaming.

Comment: @TemaniAfif As for your "wasted effort". Any question you closed, for any reason, may be reopened later. That's a part of the system's mechanics. Are your closing efforts wasted in such a case?

Comment: yes, my effort is wasted in this particular case when I close a question as a perfect duplicate. I am not talking in general when my closure can be *wrong* or the duplicate not suitable after the OP making an edit to clarify his issue.