# Is it ok to edit instead of asking a new question?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-edit

While reviewing the Reopen Votes queue, I encountered a duplicate question. Something about it seemed off - the revision was quite extensive, and from looking at the duplicate and the revised question I saw no similarities.

I went over to the question itself to investigate.  I saw that the question was closed as a duplicate, and after closure it was edited into ***a completely different question***. When I realized that, I rolled-back the question to its last revision of the original and left a comment to the OP along the lines of:

> The edit button is for clarifications and improvements, not to change
> the question completely. If you have a new question, please ask a new
> one.

Which in reply I got something along the lines of:

> I can't ask new questions and I will have to wait a long time.

My guess is that the user is probably banned. Now my question is:

Should I've been more "gentle" on the user and vote to reopen the question to disassociate it from the (now irrelevant) duplicate? I feel like that is wrong because while there were still no answers, the history of the post would look quite odd.

---

This is a bit different than [How to deal with the OP editing their question after a duplicate closure to ask a new one?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391996/6045800) as the question there was already opened and answered.

Comment: No, editing a question to ask a **completely different** question is *not* ok. It completely invalidates the dupe target and answers that *might* have been posted and (although they are 3rd rate citizens) makes the comments completely void too. It's bad enough when people post incomplete questions, get answers, and then *move* the goal posts (those should also be rolled back), but if the question is completely different, then rolling back is the right choice in my opinion.

Comment: @JeanneDark Thanks for that. Interestingly Tim's actually saying that it's fine if there were no answers... Now the question is should I go back and roll to the new question and reopen...

Comment: But it's not the answer with the highest score by far.

Comment: It’s actually not fine if there are no answers

Comment: @SecurityHound why?

Comment: Other than the fact it’s typically used to get around a question block?

Comment: I marked as duplicate as [Jean's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389661/6045800) explained it quite well

Comment: @Tomerikoo - re:: Tim - actually, I don't think there is a consensus, this turned out to be quite a controversial topic. I am also not in the camp of those who think that editing of other questions should be allowed if they don't have answers. Instead, let's rediscuss the *multi-month bans* on posting for a few bad questions. Jesus, real-world penalties are less harsh than that most of the time. Something also tells me that this penalty does not lead to the asker learning their lesson when (if) they come back [citation needed]

Comment: @OlegValter Yeah actually after closing as duplicate I still found myself confused because even Jean's answer I cited addresses comments and votes which (although I didn't mention and linked) were not in this case. There were literally no answers, no comments and no votes. In the end I decided to let it go and commented to the OP with a link to the dupe target here

Comment: Re: edits on questions with no answers: I'm not a fan. Sometimes I write an answer for a while and it's immensely frustrating if it turns out the question changed after I started writing the answer. To clarify - it's fine if there was a change to clarify the question and maybe add some omitted details. Not when it is substantially changed especially if it's not recognisable any more. I appreciate that it's a hard balance to strike some times but if an answer in flight is completely invalidated, it's not a pleasant experience.

Comment: @Tomerikoo - yeah, I guess in these cases the best conduct is just to warn the OP and move on. The last time someone tried to prevent the edits turned out in a brawl involving moderators.

Comment: @VLAZ The reason why I'm still confused about this is that the question was closed at the moment (met in the reopen queue). So in a way, no potential harm done - question closed, no answers, no comments, no votes. The only thing left is ethical(?) side of probably going around a ban. This is why I was sympathetic towards Tim's post. Is it really that bad? I still don't know...

Comment: @Tomerikoo it's tricky. If a question was closed and was modified to a completely different question, that seems bad. Especially if it's to avoid a Q ban. Closure is supposed to be a temporary state until a question is improved, not "changed in such a way that the closure is not relevant any more". However, making a substantial change to a closed question is far less risky to invalidate a potential answer. I suppose you could have a substantial *improvement* that completely re-writes the question. Not sure how likely it is but it'd be acceptable. An open question could answers in progress.

Comment: The classic is *[Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)*.